# Two class access each other by importing their head file(via #import ) causes error

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, compiler-errors

Two class access each other by importing  their head file(via #import ) causes error?

I have been always suggested to use @class className in the header file if needing to access other classes . But i've rarely got any Principle of why should i do this.  There is a small sample below, which triggers  errors like" UNKnown type name ‘xxxClass’”. Does that mean the “#import” doesn’t copy the code here ? If not so, why is it unable to detect the  ‘xxxClass’

I think this is not a cycle retain problem, but What is the principle of the error ?

```
============================  Person   ===============================

Person.h
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import "Dog.h"
 //@class Dog;
 @interface Person : NSObject
 @property (nonatomic, strong) Dog *dog;   //Error  :UNKnown type name ‘Dog'
 @end



Person.m
 #import "Person.h"
 @implementation Person
 - (void)dealloc{ NSLog(@"Person--dealloc");}
 @end

 ============================  Dog   ===============================
 Dog.h
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import "Person.h"
 @interface Dog : NSObject
 @property (nonatomic, weak) Person *person;  //Error:UNKnown type name‘Person'
 @end



Dog.m
 #import "Dog.h"
 @implementation Dog

 - (void)dealloc{ NSLog(@"Dog--dealloc");}
 @end


============================  main   ===============================
 main.m
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import "Person.h"
 #import "Dog.h"
 int main()
 {   
   Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
   Dog *d = [[Dog alloc] init];

   p.dog = d;
   d.person = p;

   return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `#import` makes the compile get the entire text of the specified file into the one where the statement was written. When you have circular `#import` statements the compiler becomes confused and throws an error. That is why you should use `@class` to break that cycle.

Comment: It is ok now!  Since   1.   A.h import B.h,      then   2.   B.h import A.h [which also import B.h],now this action means B.h will  import itself.  So the compiler becomes confused.   Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

@class Dog means that , when its starting compiling , you are telling compiler that it will have this class ( later ) and does not have to include/compile at the moment ,

you must use @class in header , 
if you want to manipulate this object from implementation ( .m file ) , then , you can include another-classes header file (.h) directly in .m file

```
//Person.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Dog;
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) Dog *dog;
@end


//Person.m
#import "Person.h"
@implementation Person
- (void)dealloc{ NSLog(@"Person--dealloc");}
@end


//Dog.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Person;
@interface Dog : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) Person *person;
@end

//Dog.m
#import "Dog.h"
// **IF YOU WANT TO HAVE ACCESS TO THE PERSONS OBJECT AND ITS PROPERTIES , INCLUDE ITS HEADER HERE**
@implementation Dog
- (void)dealloc{ NSLog(@"Dog--dealloc");}
@end

main.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"
#import "Dog.h"
int main()
{   
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
    Dog *d = [[Dog alloc] init];
    p.dog = d;
    d.person = p;

    return 0;
}
```